# React custom hook doesn't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Here i have a example hooks

```
const useGPS = () => {
  const [gps, setGps] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    setGps({ a: 1 })
  }, [])

  return [gps]
}
```

it's pretty simple, but when i use it inside another Component

```
const Foo = () => {
  const location = useGPS()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>1</div>
  )
}
```

console always log empty object for first time. Can someone explain what happened and how can i fix it? Sorry about my bad english. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you export useGPS out from that component?

Comment: @MattLaszcz yes, i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of GPS is only set after the first useEffect is run (inside the custom hook). It is initially empty and when the useEffect(foo component) runs, that empty value is shown.

The value is set successfully, and you can check this if you remove the `[]` array from the Foo component's useEffect. `[]` means that it will only run once after mounting, acting as componentDidMount.

```
export default function App() {
  const location = useGPS()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  });

  return (
    <div>1</div>
  )

}
```

Comment: What i have to do to make Foo useEffect wait until useGPS useEffect setGPS successfully?

Comment: The useEffect inside the custom hook is nothing special and will be attached(not the best word, but i hope it gets the point across) to the component when you invoke the hook. Since it is, so both useEffects will run same way and it will only depend on the dependency array you pass.

Comment: In short there is no way you can make sure that it waits. Remember hooks are supposed to be called at top level in components or inside another hook. What you can do is when second time it is run, you can then use the value. If your component is more complex, you can add `location` to the dependency array as done by @Andris. This **ensures** that the useEffect callback is only called when **location** is changing.

Comment: i saw a lot of custom hooks outside and i refer to one of them(i am practice to write custom hooks). They still can use value pass from useGPS (in this case is {a:1}) without any useEffect to watch it. Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are saying. For instance here is one on codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-with-react-memo-forked-zxjm3?file=/src/App.js. You can change code and use `[]` to see it does not work

Comment: Maybe i need to learn more about useEffect before i update the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure. If this helped you upvote and accept this answer. Else if you plan on adding an example code, please link it in the question, not in this comment thread, so everyone can see it

Answer (score 1):

To add to Tushar's answer, if you want to fix the behaviour without leaving useEffect running on every update (which can cause bugs in some more complex examples), you can add `location` to useEffect's dependencies:

```
const Foo = () => {
  const location = useGPS();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location);
  }, [location]);

  return <div>1</div>;
```

};

That way the effect will run only when a new value for `location` has been generated. You'll still see an empty object the very first time you call console.log, but it will be immediately updated to the generated value.

Answer (score 0):

const [location] = useGPS();

you need to destructor location state array

Comment: They are just logging it though, they can log the whole array